# Creating a Development Environment for Visual Studio and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, installation, environment

I need to create a development environment for myself to:
1)  Practise and self-develop 
2)  Create pet projects (which could potentially involve few other developers but that is in the distant future)

## **Software to install**

To start with I have bought a Windows 10 Professional license that I intend to install on a VM (VirtualBox). There are three software that I will need - Visual Studio, SQL Server and TFS. I suppose I have to install them in the order below:

**Visual Studio**

I know that I can install Visual Studio Community 2015 as long as I am working individually so that is sorted for now.

**SQL Server**

With SQL Server I would like to use all the BI tools (SSIS, SSRS, SSAS). Options:
I can either buy a developer edition 2014 (I do not want to spend at this point in time) 
or install the “Express with Advanced Services“ which I believe should be fine to begin with . 
The limitations and the differences are in the link below which I believe should be fine for now.

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/cc645993.aspx
>
> http://sqlknowledge.com/2014/04/sql-2014-express-edition-limitations/

Since I need to use the all the [BI tools, I will need to install the Data Tools 2015 in VS][3]. Since it still in preview version I am now considering to install VS 2013 along with its SSDT

**Version Control**

Finally I can install TFS express but it only supports express editions else I have to go for an alternative open source or a freeware version control.

## **Question**

Please can you assist me in guiding if I have got all these correct and if it will all work or do I have to buy any license or some other editions.

Please feel free to make any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of installing TFS, you can use Visual Studio Online for free if you are alone (or even a very small team): https://www.visualstudio.com/products/what-is-visual-studio-online-vs

Comment: For version control, Git/GitHub is also well supported in VS, so that's another option for you.

Comment: Thanks both. I am told of those two options but I have not yet looked further into what the differences or the limitation are. The other reason I wanted to use TFS is to learn the tool and get used to it. But other than that do you think the plan is good to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you got down voted so I voted you back up again :) - I think questions on getting a modern development stack for SQL Server development should be encouraged!

You can do your development entirely for free as long as it is genuinely for learning rather than you secretly work for a multi-million dollar corporate who really doesn't like paying for anything :)

I would get the community version of visual studio, 2015 or 2013 are both fine and I use both of them today for my personal projects.

As for SQL you can use the express versions without any licensing restrictions and as long as you are happy with the restrictions then they will work.

For TFS you can use visual studio online rather than TFS express which gives you the additional benefit that you can work from anywhere or if you break your machine you have a full backup. If you didn't use TFS then bitbucket has free private repositories or github will let you have open repositories or pay a little bit to get private repos. I personally use visual studio online and github and am very happy with both plus if you configure your tfs host to use git then moving between the two is really simple.

Overall it is a great time to be a microsoft developer and you will be fine with your setup, make sure you check out these resources for learning:

- http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/product-training/sql-server
- http://www.pluralsight.com/
- http://www.sqlpass.org/PASSChapters/VirtualChapters.aspx

The microsoft virtual academy and sql pass videos are free, plural sight has a few days free trial.

Good luck,

Ed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to spend money :) it is best to buy an MSDN subscription

As you noted you can [download and install SQL Server developer edition](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2016/download-sql-server-2016-free.aspx), it has same features with Enterprise edition. I'ld prefer to start with SQL Server 2016 since it is new and has some new features like JSON support etc which may be interesting for a developer

Visual Studio has Community Edition now which is free a you said.

Comment: Thanks Eralper but sorry I do not want to spend money at this point in time. The reason I did not mention 2016 is because it is still in preview stage. So do think what I have laid down here is ideal for a setup in the long run?